# Problem getting data out of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the following:

```
Array (
    [feed] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [title] => Stackoverflow
            [permalink] => http://www.stackoverflow.com
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [title] => Yahoo
            [permalink] => http://www.yahoo.com
        )
    )
)
```

How can I get the title? I tried this:

```
$data['feed']['title']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
foreach($data['feed'] as $val) {
 echo $val['title']
}
```

to get all titles

Answer (score 6):

Shouldn't it be this:

```
$data['feed'][0]['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the numeric index:

```
Array ( 
    [feed] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [title] => Stackoverflow[permalink] => http://www.stackoverflow.com) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [title] => Yahoo [permalink] => http://www.yahoo.com) )
     )
)
```

`$data['feed'][0]['title']`